# Entity Framework Core 6 scalar queries

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework 6, I used the SQL query

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MySeqNumber
```

to get the next sequence number through method.

```
dbCOntext.Database.SqlQuery<int>().
```

How can the same thing be done in Entity Framework Core 6?

Will the same solution apply to calling a stored procedure which returns an integer or a string?